# What is the Dissipation Factor of a capacitor useful for in its direct form?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, esr

Why do electrolytic capacitor makers provide the low frequency ESR in the form of a dissipation factor (DF) instead of an Ohms value as they do for higher frequency. The DF is rather unwieldy and I end up recalculating the ESR anyhow.

Why do they leave the burden of calculating the low frequency ESR to the user instead of doing it once for everyone when creating the spec sheet ? That suggests that the DF is a more useful number than the low frequency ESR in Ohms - contrary to my personal experience and contrary to e.g. Digikey who provide 120 Hz ESR also in Ohms when given in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The dissipation factor is simply the way the capacitor is characterized.

It's easier to measure the DF at 120Hz (often) than measure the complex impedance (the ESR is the real part) at some higher frequency.

In short: if they give you a DF the capacitor is designed as a bulk capacitor for DC or on-line rectification; if they quote and ESR the capacitor is designed for switching supply/chopper/inverter duty.

See also https://www.electrocube.com/pages/capacitors-dissipation-factor-technical-bulletin

Comment: I understand the relation between ESR and DF. The question is why do they leave the burden of calculating the low frequency ESR to the user instead of doing it **once for everyone** when creating the spec sheet ? That suggests that the DF is a more useful number than the low frequency ESR in Ohms - contrary to my personal experience and contrary to e.g. Digikey who provide 120 Hz ESR also in Ohms when given in the datasheet.

Comment: I think is a traditional/ancient thing from where electrolytics were mainly for ripple suppression and switching regulators employed SCR (for *huge* rectifier problems semikron and other still makes suitable ones, anyway). I *never* used the DF as is like you, if it make you feel safer:P